# Easy prolog queries

Tags: prolog

I am very new to prolog and although I’ve read some books I can definitely tell that my programming brain can’t think the Prolog way. The problem I would like to solve is pretty simple (I believe). I will describe it via an example.

Let’s say that I have a graph that contains 4 “types” of nodes and 3 edges that connect the nodes. The types can be A, B, C or D and as you can see from the image below (see Figure 1), A can be connected with B and C (A_To_B and A_To_C edges respectively), while C can be connected to D (C_To_D edge). There’s also an additional rule not shown on the picture: A can be connected to at most 1 C.

[image: Figure 1]

I would like to express these simple rules in Prolog to solve the problem shown in the second picture. There are 3 nodes which type is missing (labeled X?, Y? and  Z?). By applying the above rules in my mind I can easily find that X? and Z? are of B type (as A can connect to no more than 1 Cs) and Y? is of type D as C can only connect to D.

[image]

Could please provide me any help on that? I am not writing just to pick the solution. I would like to learn Prolog as well so any suggestion on a book that explains Prolog to people who have never worked on such concepts before like me would be very welcome.

*EDIT: Example that fails*

I came up with the following two examples:

[image]

For example 1, the rules are

```
can_connect(a,b,_).
can_connect(a,c,1).

link(1,2).

type(1,a).
type(2,_).
```

The possible solutions returned are [b,c] which is correct as we request **at most** 1 link from A to C meaning that 0 links is also acceptable.

In example 2 the rules change to the following:

```
can_connect(a,b,_).
can_connect(a,c,**2**).

link(1,2).
link(1,3).

type(1,a).
type(2,_).
type(3,c).
```

Running the code here returns [c] which is wrong. b is also an acceptable solution as we require again **at most** 2 A to C links which means that having only 1 is OK.

I spent this weekend trying to figure out the solution. First of all, I believe that it works as intended in Example 1 simply because there's no link from A to C instantiated in the proposed solution (where checking if 2 can be b), so the can_connect(a,c,1) is not checked so the proposed solution is getting accepted. In Example 2, there's one A to C link already there so the can_connect(a,c,2) is checked and the solution where node 2 has type b is rejected as the rule checks if there are **exactly** 2 and not **at most** 2 links from A to C.

I find a solution which works at these scenarios but fails at some others. Here it is:

```
% value #3 is the lower bound and #4 is the upper bound.
can_connect(a,b,0,500).
% A C node can be connected by 0, 1 or 2 A nodes
can_connect(a,c,0,2).
can_connect(d,c,1,1).
can_connect(c,e,0,1).

%The same as previous solution
link(1,2).
link(1,3).

% No change here
type(1,a).
type(2,_).
type(3,c).

% No change here
node_type(N, NT) :- 
    type(N, NT), 
    nonvar(NT), 
    !. % assume a node has only one type

% No change here
node_type(N, NT) :-
    assoc_types(Typed),
    maplist(check_connections(Typed), Typed),
    memberchk(N:NT, Typed).

% No change here
assoc_types(Typed) :-
    findall(N, type(N, _), L),
    maplist(typed, L, Typed).

% No change here
typed(N, N:T) :- 
    type(N, T),
    member(T, [a,b,c]).

% Changes here
check_connections(Graph, N:NT) :-
    forall(link(N, M), (
        memberchk(M:MT, Graph),
        can_connect(NT, MT, L, U),
        findall(X, (link(N, X), memberchk(X:MT, Graph)), Ts),
        mybetween(L, U, Ts),
        forall(can_connect(NT, Y, LM, UM), (
            findall(P, (link(N,P),memberchk(P:Y, Graph)), Ss),
            length(Ss, SsSize ),
            SsSize>=LM,
            SsSize=<UM
        ))
    )).

% It is used to find if the length of a list is between two limits.
mybetween(Lower, Upper, MyList) :-
    length(MyList, MySize),
    MySize=<Upper,
    MySize>=Lower.
```

This solution fails in this example

[image]

In this example, X? must be always b, Y? must always be C and Z? must always be D. It finds X? and Y? correctly but not Z?. I believe after some debugging that this is due the fact that in the current implementation I only check the can_connect rules that are related with links that **start** from a node and not that **end** to a node. However, I am not sure at all about that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's not an easy problem, do you want to discuss the solution ?

Comment: Yes, please. Thank you.

Comment: What I've done so far is to write 3 rules: edge(a,b). edge(a,c). edge(c,d). When I query ?- edge(a,X) it return b or c which is correct based on the poor set of rules I have. The difficult part for me is to represent the already existing edges so I can count them. I think that edge/2 is not sufficient as I need to create a functor for each edge i.e. egde_a_b(a,b), etc...

Comment: Which books have your read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the representation of the problem needs to disambiguate nodes names, so we can express the links appropriately

[image]

now we can write

```
can_connect(a,b,_).
can_connect(a,c,1).
can_connect(c,d,_).

link(1,2).
link(1,3).
link(1,4).
link(4,5).
link(4,6).
link(7,4).
link(7,8).

type(1,a).
type(2,b).
type(3,_).
type(4,c).
type(5,d).
type(6,_).
type(7,a).
type(8,_).
```

The underscore (anonymous variable) in Prolog plays a role similar to NULL in SQL, it can assume any value.

So, a first snippet

```
node_type(N, NT) :- type(N, NT), nonvar(NT), !. % assume a node has only one type
```

can be used to express what we know about the problem.

Facts can_connect/3 then can be read like

```
a can connect to any number of b
a can connect to just 1 c
etc
```

Where we don't know the node type, a complex rule is needed, that infers the type of source node from the type of target node, and accounts for the counting constraint, something like

```
node_type(N, NT) :-
    link(M, N),
    type(M, MT),
    can_connect(MT, NT, C),
    aggregate(count, Y^(link(M, Y), type(Y, NT)), C).

?- forall(between(1,8,N), (node_type(N,T),writeln(N:T))).
1:a
2:b
3:b
4:c
5:d
6:d
7:a
8:b
true.
```

*edit* if your Prolog doesn't have library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)), from where aggregate/3 has been loaded, you can try

```
node_type(N, NT) :-
    link(M, N),
    type(M, MT),
    can_connect(MT, NT, C),
    findall(t, (link(M, Y), type(Y, NT)), Ts), length(Ts, C).
```

*edit* first of all, the updated graph, marked with types where known:

[image: updated graph]

my previous code worked only under very restricted assumptions. Here is something more general, that checks the constraints over the full graph (as was suggested by @false comment), with a 'generate and test' approach.

```
node_type(N, NT) :-
    assoc_types(Typed),
    maplist(check_connections(Typed), Typed),
    memberchk(N:NT, Typed).

assoc_types(Typed) :-
    findall(N, type(N, _), L),
    maplist(typed, L, Typed).

typed(N, N:T) :- type(N, T), member(T, [a,b,c,d]).

check_connections(Graph, N:NT) :-
    forall(link(N, M), (
        memberchk(M:MT, Graph),
        can_connect(NT, MT, C),
        aggregate(count, X^(link(N, X), memberchk(X:MT, Graph)), C)
    )).
```

now `?- node_type(4,X).` fails...

Comment: OK. First of all thanks for the answer. I will go through it statement by statement because there are some commands I am not familiar with at the moment. I will come back to that for any questions and mark it as solved. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Using variables in this manner is highly problematic. Instead, represent the *entire graph* with one term (with variables in appropriate places).

Comment: I think that I understand all the lines of code. I have a problem running it. When I run the query you provide (forall....) it retuns N = N, T = T, Yes (I am using tkeclipse as GUI). If I run a query like ?- node_type(3,T). I get an error saying "calling an undefined procedure aggregate(...) in module eclipse. Any idea why is that?

Comment: I'm using SWI-Prolog, so library(aggregate) is autoloaded... which prolog are you using ? anyway, now I'll replace aggregate/3 with findall/3. Need just the time to test...

Comment: I confirm it works with swi-prolog. I also confirm that it works with EclipseCSP if you use the findall/3. I suppose that it works with EclipseCSP and aggregate if I find how to load the library(aggregate). Thanks.

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with this. If I change the second tree and set node #3 to b, node #4 to unknown and node #8 to c it finds a solution that node #4 can be either b or c. First of all it can't be c as node #7 is a and it is already connected to one c. It can't also be b as b can't be connected to anything. I tried both aggregate and findall solutions provided. If node #4 is b then it also says that node #6 is b which is also invalid as b can't be connected to b.

Comment: The updated 'generate and test' approach seems to work on some test examples I tried. So, first of all thanks for the help. I will now try to understand this code which is much more complex. Is there any way I can contact you directly to discuss on that?

Comment: @Thanos: I'm a bit busy right now, you could post other questions on specific parts where you need help. As I said initially, the problem is not very easy, and I took some 'trick of the trade' to keep my answer compact, but not particularly efficient or easy to understand.

Comment: I believe that the solution doesn't work. I updated my question with cases where it fails.

Comment: You should have a can_connect/4 for each arrow in Rules Model. That apart, I think your approach to collaboration here is flawed. A question should not be changed so much as, specially **not** extended. Then, unaccepting the answer is a **lot** unfair, imho

Comment: I will definitely accept your question as correct at the end of the day. I just don't won't to mislead people that the solution works at the moment. Can I have an email to contact you directly? (not to find help for the solution, just for something related with the use of the solution. It is important.) Regarding the can_connects for each rule, yes you're right. I have them but I forgot to copy-paste all of them. It still fails.